# How is the first Friedman Equation simplified to remove the Cosmological Constant?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

Following a suggestion from another [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/564894/how-is-the-curvature-term-of-the-friedmann-equation-calculated-with-the-newtonia), I'm writing a Mathematica program to derive the Friedmann Equations from GR.  After calculating the metric, the inverse metric, the Reimann tensor, the Ricci tensor and scalar, and Einstein tensor, I'm coming down the home stretch to the final equations and the program is able to derived this equality from the time-time EFE.
$$\frac{\dot a^2+k c^2}{a^2}=\frac{8\pi G \rho+\Lambda c^2}{3}$$

Which agrees with the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations) page and all the sources I can find.  However, I'm stumbling on the next step from that page.

> These equations are sometimes simplified by replacing
> $$\rho \rightarrow\rho-\frac{\Lambda c^2}{8\pi G}$$
> to give:
> $$\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^2=\frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho-\frac{kc^2}{a^2}$$

This is the original equation that I was interested in deriving because it gives the curvature, $k$, as a function of mass density.  I see this form of the first equation in many, many sources.  However, this step isn't very well documented.  What is the justification for replacing the density with $\rho-\frac{\Lambda c^2}{8\pi G}$?  Are we assuming that the Cosmological Constant is so small that it can be disregarded in this relation?

Comment: *Are we assuming that the Cosmological Constant is so small that it can be disregarded in this relation?* No. Currently the term with $\Lambda$ is the larger term.

Comment: @G.Smith - Then what's the justification for removing the term with the Cosmological Constant in it?

Comment: It isn’t removed; it is *incorporated* as a “dark energy” contribution to the energy density. The two $\rho$’s aren’t the same. There is a “$\rho$ not including $\Lambda$” and a “$\rho$ including $\Lambda$”. Yes, it’s confusing. When you think that physicists are morons for theorizing about dark energy, as I believe you have previously opined, realize that it is nothing more than the cosmological constant, which is the most natural thing in the world if one accepts GR. It is literally the zeroth-order term in an expansion of the gravitational action in powers of curvature.

Comment: @G.Smith - Which one is which?  Which $\rho$ are we using in the Perfect Fluid Stress Energy Momentum tensor?  I thought it was the volumetric mass density.  Let's call that $\rho_m$.  Let's call the energy density $\rho_e$ such that, $$\rho_e=\rho_m c^2$$Can you write that substitution now so it is less confusing?  Is the $\rho$ in the final Friedmann equation interpreted as $$\rho=\rho_{total}-\rho_c \Omega_{\Lambda}$$

Comment: $8\pi G \rho_{\text{without }\Lambda}+\Lambda c^2= 8\pi G \rho_{\text{with }\Lambda}$

Comment: @G.Smith - Which ρ are we using in the Perfect Fluid Stress Energy Momentum tensor?

Comment: Either one, depending on whether you write the Einstein field equations with or without a $\Lambda$ term on the left side. If you prefer to omit $\Lambda$ from the left side, then you use a $\rho$ that includes $\Lambda$ on the right side.

Comment: @G.Smith - Just to be clear. Are you saying that the $\rho$ in this equation:$$\frac{\dot a^2+k c^2}{a^2}=\frac{8\pi G \rho+\Lambda c^2}{3}$$ is the $\rho_{with\Lambda}$ (that is, the mass density of everything in a cube of space) and the $\rho$ in this equation:$$\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^2=\frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho-\frac{kc^2}{a^2}$$is the $\rho_{without\Lambda}$ (i.e. the density of everything except 'Dark Energy')

Comment: No, the opposite. In the first, $\Lambda$ has not been incorporated into $\rho$ so that is the without-dark-energy version of the energy density.

Comment: @G.Smith - OK. I think I get it now. You are just burying the $\frac{\Lambda c^2}{3}$ term in a new density parameter. So if we use the abbreviated Friedman equation (that is, the one with the density substitution) with real values to solve for density, then what we're actually solving for is this new all-inclusive density term. So if we actually wanted the mass density of matter, photons and neutrinos in a cubic meter, then we'd have to remove the 'Dark Energy' density somehow.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.